# How to load data from a downloaded tar.gz file in tensorflow/keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset

Tensorflow datasets or tfds automatically starts downloading the data I want. I have cifar10 downloaded in my system. I can directly load the data in pytorch using:
torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10('path/to/directory',...,download=False)

Is there a tensorflow or keras equivalent of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the best you can do is first extract the tar file:

```
import tarfile

if fname.endswith("tar.gz"):
    tar = tarfile.open(fname, "r:gz")
    tar.extractall()
    tar.close()
elif fname.endswith("tar"):
    tar = tarfile.open(fname, "r:")
    tar.extractall()
    tar.close()
```

and then access to the model data and load it using keras:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/load_model

Comment: Pretty late, but thank you for posting an answer regardless! I resorted to something like this in the end, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Posting another way to load the file from local for whoever finds it later.

In the URL parameter, you supply the local URL of the file with the path. For example, I have a file in my D drive in the folder Workspace/DataFiles/tldr.gz, then the value that I give for the URL parameter would be something like this.

```
path = 'file:///D:/Workspace/DataFiles/tldr.gz'

path_to_downloaded_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file("tldr_data",path, archive_format='tar', untar=True)`
```

This way keras recognizes the URL and loads the data from the file.

Answer (score 0):

How to get filename/dirname of the extracted `tar.gz` for the file that was downloaded with `HTTP`(`S`) using [tf.keras.utils.get_file()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/get_file) function:

```py
import os
from tensorflow import keras

# `fname` in the following function is an equivalent to
# `wget`'s `-O` parameter. It is needed so that the download
# function know under which name to save the downloaded file.
file_path = keras.utils.get_file(fname='ucf101_top5.tar.gz',
                                 origin='https://zenodo.org/record/7924745/files/ucf101_top5.tar.gz',
                                 extract=True)

keras_datasets_dir = os.path.dirname(file_path)

# Assuming that you know of the contents of the archive to be extracted:
dataset_dir = os.path.join(keras_datasets_dir, 'ucf101_top5')

print(dataset_dir)
```

Example output:

```
'/Users/mbuch/.keras/datasets/ucf101_top5'
```

Of course you have to know the name of the extracted directory/content of the file you are downloading for this example to work.