# How to read and load tarfile to extract feature vector

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use inception_v3 feature vectors for image classification. I have downloaded the tar file from tfhub which is a tar.gz file. The link to the feature vectors is "https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v3/feature_vector/5". This will give me the model without the classification layer.
I have downloaded the tar file and extracted it using tarfile library. But i'm not sure how to load/read the extracted file for using the feature vectors for classification.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load data from a downloaded tar.gz file in tensorflow/keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57433653/how-to-load-data-from-a-downloaded-tar-gz-file-in-tensorflow-keras)

Comment: Yes it does. works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tarfile` module to extract tar.gz files and load the model with `tf.keras.models.load_model`

```
import tarfile
  
# open file
file = tarfile.open('imagenet_inception_v3_feature_vector_5.tar.gz')
  
# extracting file
file.extractall('/content/Destination_FolderName')
  
file.close()

#loading the saved file
tf.keras.models.load_model("/content/Destination_FolderName")
```